# Django admin: deletion of linked elements

Tags: django, django-admin

in Django admin site when you decide to suppress an object, all the linked element (ie: elements pointed at by a foreign key) are also deleted.

How do you dodge this, except making raw queries in the shell?
Is it possible to tune the admin to have the choice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hack around it, but there is no proper way of doing it.

Take a look at these links for possible workarounds:

- [What are the options for overriding Django's cascading delete behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475249/what-are-the-options-for-overriding-djangos-cascading-delete-behaviour)
- http://django.mar.lt/2010/07/cascade-behaviour.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override the delete method of the models in question.

Generic example:

```
class Foo:

    def delete(self):
        """
        Override default model method so that all objects in the related
        objects set are not removed
        """
        self.my_related_stuff.clear()
        super(Foo, self).delete()
```

See this article for more examples:

http://fragmentsofcode.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/django-gotcha-related-objects-deleted-by-default/