# Django on_delete=models.SET to return Model or cascade delete

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Sorry if the title of this question sucks but I couldn't find much info on this particular problem. In the docs, the code below is given:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def get_sentinel_user():
    return User.objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
```

In such a scenario, is there any way by which I can make MyModel delete itself depending on the return value of get_sentinel_user?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475249/what-are-the-options-for-overriding-djangos-cascading-delete-behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to delete an instantiated class object from within the class itself. I do not believe this is possible. Is it possible to do this check before creating MyModel?